# How to make an object edit images each time it's run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create an object in *Javascript* & *Jquery* and assign to it 2 images (the amount is careless).

But as I need to edit those images **during the code** and they **both** have an ***id***,
I need to know how to assign to the object always the same 2 images but to edit them in a different way each time, this is what I mean:

I got a **bulb** which needs to be charged, **one** is charged in **10** seconds, **another** one maybe in **15**, so:

How do I assign to an object always the **same images**, but edit them in a **different way** (almost) each time?

Note I'l call that object more times, but then I'll change the seconds or whatever after calling it (at least this is what I've thought).

If you need to have an idea of what it'll look like, [check this](http://goo.gl/0pP1ui) :)

Comment: I don't understand what you want and how your provided fiddle does not satisfy your requirements

Comment: So, it might seem a hard thing but believe me I guess it's not: what I want to do is to create an object (the bulb) which is formed always by 2 images. The issue is that I need it as an object to create it any time I call it, but each bulb gets charged in a different amount of time, and the 'charge' thing is simply a CSS property editing (clip property) . So My question is how can I make these objects edit those images in a different way without adding them each time I need a new bulb?

Comment: So, you really only need one bulb, but want to be able to change the charge-time (when you click on it or something)? But at the moment, you have to add a new bulb (and remove the old one?) whenever you want to change the charge-time? Do I understand it correct now?

Comment: Yes @myfunkyside, you're really close to it, please let me explain in a few words the 'game': you have a counter of Watts, with those you can click on the button next to the bulb and charge it of that amount of Watts, until it's fully charged. But during the process I divide those amount of Watts you submit by 2 in the FIRST bulb, and then send that value to be converted in the 'yellow part' (charged part). What I ant to do is to create bulbs as a single object and then, if possible, add the number that should divide the amount of Watts maybe as a parameter, example: bulb(2); or bulb(4);

Comment: I invite you to check out my entire code, but keep an eye on the JS mostly :) [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/Snip3r_bow/3r6Lynce/14/)

Comment: Okay, I think I'm starting to understand, But then for starters, you would need a script that dynamically creates a new bulb in the first place, right? Because right now, that one bulb is already on the page, it's not created through JavaScript

Comment: Exactly, you understood that right ;) That's What I Want to do, creating different bulbs dinamically

Comment: @myfunkyside did you make that code I've seen on my JSFiddle? Just wondering eh :)

Comment: Yeah, in http://jsfiddle.net/3r6Lynce/17/ (and 15) I improved your code a bit by removing some redundancies in the click-function, encapsulating all the bulb-elements into a containing DIV (which is the first step in making the template bulb-object you want), and made some other minor changes/improvements. You can check it out and use it if you want.

Comment: Thanks man, I've corred 2 mistake (typo) and implemented the calling of the object.. now it works great!

Comment: You wanna check it? :)

Comment: In http://jsfiddle.net/3r6Lynce/16/ I started working on what you actually want, but then stopped/paused because I realized there would be needed so much work to get it to work exactly how you would want it

Comment: Wait, are you talking about number 16 or 15/17? Which one did you get to work? Do you mean you have what you want now? Sure, yeah show it to me:)

Comment: This is your edited code, which got a new editing by me, take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Snip3r_bow/pahLhwLb/2/

Comment: Essentially it works, but I thought you wanted to add more bulbs, as in a few bulbs next to eachother.. for that to work you still need to rewrite your code a bit. Or did I misunderstand that, do you only need the one bulb, and just need to change the `devider`?

Comment: Nope, you got it right, really, but I guess that in this way I'd just like to create a bulb, make it charge and then fadeit out and creating a new one, harder to charge. On my code there's just one thing that doesn't.. should be there: when I create the new bulb, the counter starts over from 0, that's 'cause of the '0' in the inital <span>, any ideas how to never reset it or to get the last amount?

Comment: Maybe setting at the end a variable with the value of the span #W and at the beginning of the counter implement an if statement to check if that variable exists? In that case overwriting the 'value' variable, any ideas otherwise?

Comment: @myfunkyside check it out, I've improved it again, now it keeps the last value of the #W id so your counter keeps increasing instead of starting over from 0 after charged a bulb :)

Comment: Looks nice! You want me to make it so you can really add a bulb by clicking a button? Then I'll put that in an answer so people know the question is resolved

Comment: Well I'd because I'd like to see how that's possible, but I guess you already answered me in a great way man, thanks!

Comment: I posted my answer. Hope you like it:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check this code snippet:**

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
  var chargeInterval;

/*CREATE BULB-------------------------------------------*/
  function createBulb(divider, chargeValue) {
    var newBulb = document.createElement("div"); //dynamically create new bulb
    newBulb.setAttribute("id","bulb"+divider); //set new bulb's ID
    newBulb.setAttribute("class","bulb"); //set new bulb's class

    //fill new bulb
    newBulb.innerHTML = '<div class="container">' + 
      '<img class="bulb_dark" src="http://hideme.altervista.org/Light_it_up/images/bulb.png" />' +
      '<img class="bulb_light" src="http://hideme.altervista.org/Light_it_up/images/bulb_light.png" />' +
      '<img class="charged" src="http://hideme.altervista.org/Light_it_up/images/charged.png" />' +
      '<div class="Watt"><div><span class="W">'+chargeValue+'</span><span>W</span></div><input type="button" class="Wsender" value="Charge" /></div>' + 
      '</div>';

    //start charge-counter
    chargeInterval = setInterval(function() {
      var value = parseInt($("#bulb" + divider + " .W").html(), 10);
      value++;
      $("#bulb" + divider + " .W").html(value);
    }, 10);

    //add bulb to bulbs-container
    $("#bulbs").append(newBulb);

    //fade-in bulb
    $("#bulb" + divider + " .bulb_dark").fadeIn(500);
  }

/*CLICK CHARGE-BUTTON-----------------------------------*/
  $("#bulbs").on("click", ".bulb .Wsender", function() {
    var bulb = '#' + $(this).closest(".bulb").attr("id"); //get bulb's ID
    var divider = parseInt(bulb.substr("#bulb".length)); //get divide-amount from ID

    var clipTop = parseInt($(bulb + " .bulb_light").css("clip").split(" ")[0].replace("rect(", ""), 10); //extract top-clipping from "rect(260px 160px 260px 0px)"
    var value = parseInt($(bulb + " .W").html(), 10); //Watt
    var valuee = value / divider;
    var newTop = clipTop - valuee;

    //calculate new value
    if (valuee > clipTop) {
      value -= valuee;
    } else {
      value = 0;
    }
    //update bulb's charge-level, and (re)set wattage
    $(bulb + " .bulb_light").css("clip", "rect(" + newTop + "px,160px,260px,0px)");
    $(bulb + " .W").html(value);

    //bulb is fully charged
    if (newTop <= 0) {
      $(bulb + " .Wsender").prop("disabled", true); //disable button
      $(bulb + " .Wsender").prop("value", "Charged"); //change button-label
      $(bulb + " .charged").css("display", "block"); //show fully charged bulb-image
      clearInterval(chargeInterval); //stop charge-interval
      $(bulb + " .Watt").remove(); //remove Watt-counter and charge-button

      //initiatie new bulb
      setTimeout(function() {
        var times = $(".bulb").length; //count the number of bulbs on the page
        var money = parseInt($("#money").html().substr("Money earned: ".length), 10);

        //calculate money
        if (times <= 10) {
          money += 25;
        } else if (10 < times&&times <= 20) {
          money += 50;
        } else if (20 < times&&times <= 30) {
          money += 75;
        } else if (30 < times&&times <= 40) {
          money += 100;
        } else if (40 < times&&times <= 50) {
          money += 150;
        } else if (50 < times&&times <= 60) {
          money += 300;
        } else if (60 < times&&times <= 70) {
          money += 500;
        }
        $("#money").html("Money earned: " + money);
        $("#times").html("Bulbs charged: " + times);

        //create new bulb
        createBulb(divider+1, value); //increase divider for next bulb
      }, 500);
    }
  });
  
  createBulb(1,0); //(divider,chargeValue)
});
```

```css
#score {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
}
#bulbs {
  background-color: #dadada;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 2% 10px 2%;
  overflow: hidden; /*needed for auto-height to work*/
}

/*BULB--------------------------*/
.bulb {
  float: left;
  width: 160px; /*must be equal to .bulb_dark width*/
  height: 260px; /*must be equal to .bulb_dark height*/
}
.bulb .container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px; /*must be equal to .bulb_dark width*/
  height: 260px; /*must be equal to .bulb_dark height*/
}
.bulb .bulb_dark {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
.bulb .bulb_light {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  clip: rect(260px, 160px, 260px, 0px);
}
.bulb .charged {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
.bulb .Watt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 160px; /*must be equal to .bulb_dark width*/
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="score">
  <div id="money">Money earned: 0</div>
  <div id="times">Bulbs charged: 0</div>
</div>
<div id="bulbs"></div>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pahLhwLb/15/**)

Basically, in order to dynamically add bulbs, you need a function that creates a new bulb, i.e. adds all the elements that a bulb consists of.
Whenever you want to create a new bulb, you just call that function.

- In `createBulb()`, a new div is created and given the bulb-class and a unique ID. This ID contains the divider (the amount with which you want to divide the charge-value). This new bulb is added at the end of the function.
- At the end of the click-function - if the current bulb is fully charged - the create-function is called again: `createBulb(divider+1, value);`, where the current divider is increased and send along as an argument.
  As you requested, the current charge-value is also send along, so that the charge-counter doesn't reset but continues instead.

*A few other notes:*

- You have to use `class` instead of `id`, because ID's must be unique (there can only be one). Since you're creating multiple bulbs, you can't have them all have the same ID.
- I removed your `window.divider = divider;`. You don't need it, because you already have the amount stored in a variable inside of the function.
  If you would have needed it, I would advise you to move it to the top of the script, outside of the function. This is good practice, because now you have a better overview of all the global variables you're creatingion. (And if you do that, you don't need the `window.` part.)
- I changed your `switch` to an if-clause. I could be wrong, but I think that if you use the switch in the way you do, an if-clause is actually more efficient. I also changed the format of the conditions from `(times > 10 && times <= 20)` to `(10 < times&&times <= 20)`, just to make it easier readable (in my opinion). Needless to say, you are free to discard this and use your own style instead.
- I changed your `new_value` to `newValue`. This is just common practice; in JavaScript variables are named using the camelCase-format, in PHP the underscore-format is more common. Again, feel free to change it back.

*One last time:) Some of my changes have more to do with personal style/preference than with being 'the correct way'. Naturally you should feel free to change those back to your own personal style of coding.*

Comment: Wow, amazing man, I guess I'm gonna edit it all again (by adding stuff not removing ahaha) I really wish to make it better